# simple SQL query to LinQ , i have tried but not solved yet

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have the following SQL Server query and I need to have it in LINQ, Simple query but I tried several time but I can not get it working.

Here is the SQL query

```
select * 
from td_Accountline 
where 
    BonusPlanID = 1
    and Amount > 0
    and Ord_Sub_ID like '%SMPORD%' 
    and MONTH(Created) = 11
    and YEAR(Created) = 2013  
    and Ord_Sub_ID not in (
        select Ord_Sub_ID 
        from td_Accountline 
        where 
            BonusPlanID =3 and
            Ord_Sub_ID like '%SMPORD%'
    )
```

I have tried with this query but still i am confused

```
var account=from acc in currentDB.td_Accountline
                                              where acc.BonusPlan.BonusPlanID == 1 && acc.Amount > 0 && acc.Ord_Sub_ID.Contains("SMPORD") && acc.Created.ToDateTime().Month == 11 && acc.Created.ToDateTime().Year == 2013
                                              let accNot = from accN in currentDatabase.td_Accountline
                                                           where accN.BonusPlan.BonusPlanID == 3 && accN.Ord_Sub_ID.Contains("SMPORD")
                                                           select accN.Ord_Sub_ID
                                              where !accNot.Contains("SMPORD")
                                              select acc;
```

I want one query please not separate query to reduce database calling.

Comment: Can you post the linq query you said you've tried?

Comment: you can try this:  `http://sqltolinq.com/`

Comment: @FelixPamittan, Please see my updated post .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're almost there. Instead of:

```
where !accNot.Contains("SMPORD")
```

It should be:

```
where !accNot.Contains(acc.Ord_Sub_ID)
```

Your final Linq query would be:

```
var account = from acc in currentDB.td_Accountline
              where 
                acc.BonusPlan.BonusPlanID == 1
                && acc.Amount > 0
                && acc.Ord_Sub_ID.Contains("SMPORD")
                && acc.Created.Month == 11 
                && acc.Created.Year == 2013
              let accNot = from accN in currentDatabase.td_Accountline
                           where 
                            accN.BonusPlan.BonusPlanID == 3
                            && accN.Ord_Sub_ID.Contains("SMPORD")
                            select accN.Ord_Sub_ID
              where !accNot.Contains(acc.Ord_Sub_ID)
              select acc;
```

Comment: I cannot convert to IList<td_Accountline> AccountlineList = accountlineMissingEntry.ToList(); Error message: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Try removing the `.toDateTime()`. See updated answer.

Comment: No extention method Month & Year 
&& acc.Created.Month == 11
 && acc.Created.Year == 2013

Comment: What's the datattype of `Created`?

Comment: datatype is  DateTime

Comment: Try using `acc.Created.Value.Month`.

Comment: Glad to have been of help!

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions  won't work in Linq for Entity Framework but you can convert to collection in an in-memory list for you to use Regex.
Something like this:

```
(from x in td_Accountline where Created.Month = 11 && Created.Year = 2013 select a).ToList().Where(v => Regex.IsMatch(v.Ord_Sub_ID,@"(SMPORD)"))
```

That way, the match will happen in memory

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
var Ord_Sub_IDs = from n in td_Accountline where n.BonusPlanID == 3 && n.Ord_Sub_ID.Contains("SMPORD") select n.Ord_Sub_ID ;

var result=from n in td_Accountline where n.BonusPlanId == 1 && n.Amount > 0 && n.Ord_Sub_ID.Contains("SMPORD") && n.Created.ToDateTime().Month == 11 && n.Created.ToDateTime().Year == 2013 && Ord_Sub_IDs.Contains(td.Ord_Sub_ID) select n;
```